# Query with join taking too long to run - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a query that it's taking too long to run.
I'm using PostgreSQL 10.3.
In my tables involved in this query, I have about 3.5 million records in each.
The query is:

```
SELECT thf.attr1, thf.attr2, thf.attr3, thf.attr4
FROM tb_one AS thf
INNER JOIN tb_two AS ths
ON ths.tb_hit_hitid = thf.tb_hit_hitid
WHERE ths.source IN ('source1', 'source2')
```

In these tables, I have index:

```
CREATE INDEX tb_two_idx_1 on tb_two (Source ASC, attr5 ASC);
CREATE INDEX tb_one_idx_1 on tb_one USING btree (attr1 ASC,attr2 ASC,attr3 ASC,attr4 ASC);
CREATE INDEX tb_one_idx_2 on tb_hit_feature (tb_hit_HitId ASC);
CREATE INDEX tb_two_idx_2 on tb_hit_source (tb_hit_HitId ASC);
```

This is the QUERY PLAN (`explain (analyse, buffers)`):

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=3.85..287880.35 rows=1771004 width=44) (actual time=0.091..3894.024 rows=1726970 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (thf.tb_hit_hitid = ths.tb_hit_hitid)
   Buffers: shared hit=354821
   ->  Index Scan using tb_one_idx_2 on tb_one thf  (cost=0.43..124322.43 rows=3230800 width=52) (actual time=0.014..655.036 rows=1726946 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=27201
   ->  Index Scan using tb_two_idx_2 on tb_two ths  (cost=0.43..139531.97 rows=1771004 width=8) (actual time=0.069..1604.789 rows=1726973 loops=1)
         Filter: ((source)::text = ANY ('{source1,source2}'::text[]))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1651946
         Buffers: shared hit=327620
 Planning time: 2.737 ms
 Execution time: 4117.573 ms
(11 rows)
```

Comment: Your where condition selects about 1.8M rows from one table based on second table. I don't know what kind of performance do you expect from it - the plan is perfect for these conditions. It might be that your work_mem is too low for this and the db has to use the disk for a temporary file - you can post `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select ...` to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT thf.attr1, thf.attr2, thf.attr3, thf.attr4
FROM tb_one thf INNER JOIN
     tb_two ths
     ON ths.tb_hit_hitid = thf.tb_hit_hitid
WHERE ths.source IN ('source1', 'source2');
```

You want indexes on `tb_two(source, tb_hit_hitid)` and `tb_one(tb_hit_hitid)`.  That is probably the best index.

In case the query returns duplicates (due to the join), I might suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT thf.attr1, thf.attr2, thf.attr3, thf.attr4
FROM tb_one thf
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tb_two ths
              WHERE ths.tb_hit_hitid = thf.tb_hit_hitid AND
                    ths.source IN ('source1', 'source2')
             );
```

For this version, you want the index to be `tb_two(tb_hit_hitid, source)`.

Comment: Depending on the distribution of values, isn't it possible `tb_two(tb_hit_hitid, source)` will be better?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus . . . For the first query?  I doubt it.  You probably want to filter by the `where` clause first.  I mean, I suppose it is possible that the index ordering doesn't make a difference, but normally the filter on `where` would be first.

Comment: — my thinking was that `thf.source` may have too few distinct values to be worth indexing while the join might be highly selective.